# dotnet publish profile CLI vs Visual Studio behave different

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-core

I have a dotnet core 2.1 web API project with a publish profile to a folder that lately I plan to copy to an IIS as in [dotnet publish documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21).

I created the publish profile with VS and the resulting file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <ProjectGuid>b3155c62-817f-4eba-8856-e5941137f4ed</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <_IsPortable>false</_IsPortable>
    <publishUrl>bin\publish\</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

If I run the profile from VS it creates a `bin\publish` folder that I can copy to IIS.

If I do the same with `dotnet publish /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile` (as in the CI server) after updating to latest VS I get the following error

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets(122,5): error NETSDK1067: Self-contained applications are required to use the application host. Either set SelfContained to false or set UseAppHost to true. [C:\Users\Guillem.Sola\source\repos\ASG.DHW.HealthCheck\ASG.DHW.HealthCheck.API\ASG.DHW.HealthCheck.API.csproj]`

I can achieve something similar excuting in cmd

`dotnet publish .\HealthCheck.API\HealthCheck.API.csproj -o .\bin\publish -r win-x64 -c Release`

What is going on, why the profile is not behaving the same when calling from CLI?

Comment: if you haven't updated your .net core sdk in a while, this might apply: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/5309

Comment: @JoshE as per your suggestion I have updated VS (it was updated 1 month ago) and now I have an error when executing on console. Adding more details to question

Answer (score 2):

I think that the key to your (updated) issue might be in this part of the error message:

> Self-contained applications are required to use the application host. Either set SelfContained to false or set UseAppHost to true.

The difference in behaviors could easily be explained by a number of things, like MSBuild target files brought in by various VS conditions, for example.

Because you don't want to use the AppHost, you'll need to change`<SelfContained>true</SelfContained>` to `<SelfContained>false</SelfContained>`. You could also consider adding an explicit `<UseAppHost>false</UseAppHost>` - that might help mitigate differences between a VS and a CI build.

Turning on/up the MSBuild verbosity is a good way to get more data to help you understand why the operation has the observed results.

Comment: I see, btw SelfContained is something that I want as I don't plan to install the fw on the machine. Do you mean then that calling a profile from console behaves completly different :O I'm afraid I will need to turn on the verbose log XD

Comment: Thanks! setting `--self-contained=false` solved the issue. Now the result of VS and the `dotnet publish ...` cmd is the same!
God, thanks!